# 8th SharifCTF — What is the advisable way to recover the key of single round DES here?

Tags: keys, des, known-plaintext-attack

I am participating in the [8th SharifCTF competition](http://ctf.sharif.edu/ctf8/) and have a related question:

I have 1000 plaintext and its ciphertext, which has been encrypted with  DES algorithm (only 1 round).

Now, how can I get this 64-bit hexadecimal key?

Can we use a known plaintext attack, or would another attack be more advisable? If, which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we use a known plaintext attack

Considering that you have 1,000 plaintext-ciphertext pairs, you should be able to.

### Known plaintext attack(s)

Try applying [linear cryptanalysis](http://www.theamazingking.com/crypto-linear.php), DES is relatively weak against it.

Alternatively, you could try [differential cryptanalysis](http://www.theamazingking.com/crypto-diff.php); DES is usually considered to be relatively strong against it, but with only a single round you might still make some headway.

> or would another attack be more advisable? If, which one?

### Chosen plaintext attack

Do you have access to an encryption oracle? If not, then you can't perform a [chosen-plaintext attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/what-is-the-difference-between-known-plaintext-attack-and-chosen-plaintext-attac#2847).

### Chosen ciphertext attack

Do you have access to a decryption oracle? If not, then you can't perform a [chosen-ciphertext attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/how-does-a-chosen-ciphertext-attack-work-with-a-simple-example).

### Slide attack

Since the cipher is a reduced round variant that uses only a single round, you cannot use a [slide attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_attack).

### Brute force

You could probably rent a supercomputing cluster and simply [crack the key with brute force](http://www.interhack.net/pubs/des-key-crack/). This is probably the slowest, most expensive, and least enlightening technique, but it will work against regular (not triple) DES.